# cudaEventSynchronize from multiple threads

Tags: cuda

If I call `cudaEventSynchronize` for different events in different threads, will each thread wait for the corresponding event independently? I mean, when one event finishes, the corresponding thread will be allowed to proceed while other threads may still be waiting.

Comment: Yes, that is what should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the CUDA driver and runtime have been thread-safe (and callable from multiple threads concurrently) for several releases now.

Comment: My first answer was just "Yes." but Stack Overflow's party pooper of a filter rejected it.